# Data on the BBN C/70?

Tags: minicomputers, arpanet

I am trying to find info on the BBN C/70, a 1970s minicomputer (roughly equivalent to a high-end PDP-11) which played a role in the early days of the ARPANET (predecessor or Internet)

The thing that intrigues me about this machine is that its word length was 20 bits. Since I am in the process of building a 20-bit wide [homebrew TTL machine](https://hackaday.io/project/187142-onan-1111) myself, I would be interested to know more about its BBN forebear.

Any manuals/pictures/articles (especially h/w related) would be most welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C/70 is a follow up to he C/30 which was designed as a replacement/emulation  of the Honeywell x16 series used as IMP.

The C/30 is a 20 bit implementation using what BBN called their *'Microprogramable building blocks'*, emulating the Honeywell 16 bit CPU. So a good start might be looking at C/30 manuals, specific the [Native Mode Firmware System Programmer's Reference Manual](https://walden-family.com/impcode/c30-nmfs-programmers-refererence-bbn-tr-3000.pdf). It includes detailed information of the ISA, including operation encoding.

As so often Bitsavers might provide additional sniplets, like in the

- [BBN Hardware directory](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/bbn/), especially the [IMP subdir](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/bbn/imp/), and
- [BBN Software directory](http://www.bitsavers.org/bits/BBN/) with the [1.34 TENEX](http://www.bitsavers.org/bits/BBN/Tenex/) software

---

P.S.:

a) Resistor arrays were standard in the 1970,

b) C was considered weird stuff for system programming. Real men used Assembler. Including for the BBN CPUs :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know about resistor arrays and C ... I just have an idealized vision of those years. Please don't rob me of my dreams.

Comment: @fi11222 Sorry for having lived thru them working on these machines ... (BTW, Boards were as well not green, but 'nature coloured', so grey or yellow-brownish-grey:))

Comment: @Raffzahn I forget. Did they switch from phenolic resin to fiberglass laminates before or after they started using solder mask? The timelines I've seen have never gone into that much detail.

Comment: I think this IMP software is more relevant to the C/30: https://www.walden-family.com/impcode/c30-nmfs-programmers-refererence-bbn-tr-3000.pdf

Comment: It's my understanding that the C/70 instruction set was not related to the C/30, so there's probably not much help to be had anyway.

Comment: TENEX doesn't have anything to do with the MBB, C/30, C/70.

Answer (score 6):

It wasn't a follow-up, it was an alternate microcode load. (I used one for a summer as an intern, supporting the PSN group) The instruction set was evidently modeled after the PDP 11/70, and had very little in common with the C-30, which did not support C. (e.g. I don't think the C-30 didn't have instruction support for stack-relative addressing, and constants had to be loaded from the local code page of 512 20-bit words. They were talking about a C compiler for it in 1986, but I think they moved to a 68K system before that happened)

The C/70 ran a version of Unix that seemed ancient at the time (RFC 801 says it was UNIX Version 7), and programming in C was a little bit weird because bytes were 10 bits.

For a bit more info see https://elists.isoc.org/pipermail/internet-history/2017-October/004324.html
Note that it looks like they might not have ever documented the machine language, as its only use would have been deep in the kernel.